# Flutter no activity found to handle intent

Tags: flutter, flutterwebviewplugin, flutter-inappwebview, flutter-html

I have a webview and I tried to launch intent in webview it should run the RawBT app and print what intent provides. But this error is shown.

```
Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(ACTIVITY_NOT_FOUND, No Activity found to handle intent { intent:**********************%0A**********************%0A*******************%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Skovkiosken%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0ASlotsgade%2099,%209000%20Aalborg%0A%20%20%20%20Tlf%20nr.:%2011223344%0A%20%20%20%20CVR%20nr.:%2012345678%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20******%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Kvittering%20Nr:%20%20387%0A%20%20Dato:%20%2019.08.2022%2016:21%0A----------------------------------------%0A1x35%20-%20Pita%20Kebab%20+%20%0D%0A..........................45,00%0D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20*******%0A%0A*TOTAL%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20DKK%2045,00%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20*Moms%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20DKK%20%2011.25%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20**********************%0A%20Betalingsmetode%20%20*Mobilepay*%0A%0A%20%20%20%20***TAK%20FOR%20BESOEGET***%0A%0A%0A#Intent;scheme=rawbt;package=ru.a402d.rawbtprinter;end; }, null, null)
```

Here is my webview

```
WebView(
          onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
            _controller = controller;
            _controller.clearCache();
          },
          navigationDelegate: (navigation) async {
            if (navigation.url.contains("intent")) {
              await launchUrlString(navigation.url);
            }
            return NavigationDecision.navigate;
          },
          javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
          initialUrl: "",
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

write this in your Android Menifest File

```
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <data android:scheme="https" />
    </intent>

</queries>
```